# Did I measure document.getElementById's speed correctly?

Tags: javascript, performance

I wanted to find out if there was a faster way to select a DOM element by its id, rather than document.getElementById. I did some research and found that I could select an id by its global namespace. Instead of doing this:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
console.log(document.getElemenetById('myElement'));
</script>
```

I could do this:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
console.log(myElement);
</script>
```

But I read that referencing a global namespace is 1) slow, 2) makes bad code and 3) is difficult for other developers to understand. I then tested the performance like so:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>
<div id="myElement2"></div>

<script>
var a = performance.now();
console.log(myElement);
var b = performance.now();

var c = performance.now();
console.log(document.getElementById('myElement2'));
var d = performance.now();

console.log("Global call took " + (b - a) + " milliseconds.");
console.log("By Id call took " + (d - c) + " milliseconds.");
</script>
```

And yes, the global namespace was slower. But if I did put the global namespace variable in a "local" constant variable, like this:

```
const myElement= myElement;
```

And I cached the `document.getElemenetById()` one like so:

```
const myElement2 = document.getElemenetById('myElement2');
```

I then ran my performance script again and noted that `myElement` was slower. I then switched the order of them in my code, and noticed `myElement2` was slower.

I literally just changed this:

```
var a = performance.now();
console.log(myElement);
var b = performance.now();

var c = performance.now();
console.log(myElement2);
var d = performance.now();

console.log("Global call took " + (b - a) + " milliseconds.");
console.log("By Id call took " + (d - c) + " milliseconds.");
```

to this:

```
var c = performance.now();
console.log(myElement2);
var d = performance.now();

var a = performance.now();
console.log(myElement);
var b = performance.now();

console.log("Global call took " + (b - a) + " milliseconds.");
console.log("By Id call took " + (d - c) + " milliseconds.");
```

I then ran them independently in a loop so that they'd run 1000x, and then I compared the speed. According to my findings, the global namespace selector, when was cached as a constant local variable, is slightly faster.

So before I tell the world I found a faster solution that `document.getElementById`, my question is: **did I measure this correctly?**

Comment: No. The only thing you are measuring is the speed at which `console.log` is logging the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misconception. Actually, when you are storing the dive into the constant, it's taking the same time as the normal approach. Then what are you missing?

You are measuring the performance of `console.log()` function. In the following:

```
var c = performance.now();
console.log(myElement2);
var d = performance.now();
```

But you are not counting the time to find the div and assign it to `myElement2` this constant. I mean this line is not in your measurement.

```
const myElement2 = document.getElemenetById('myElement2');
```

Don't think that when you are logging `myElement2`, then it starts to find the div. It's been when you are writing this --- `const myElement2 = document.getElemenetById('myElement2');`

So your performance measurement procedure should be like the following.

```
var c = performance.now();
const myElement2 = document.getElemenetById('myElement2');
console.log(myElement2);
var d = performance.now();

var a = performance.now();
const myElement = document.getElemenetById('myElement')
console.log(myElement);
var b = performance.now();

console.log("Global call took " + (b - a) + " milliseconds.");
console.log("By Id call took " + (d - c) + " milliseconds.");
```

And I think the time should be the same as the normal approach. Actually, there is nothing new except the variable.

Comment: Interesting. I wondered about that. I made this JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ksen3p02/3/). Would that reflect the speed more correctly?

Comment: Include the declaration also.
//global namesapce
c = performance.now();
myElement = document.querySelector('#myElement');
console.log(myElement);
d = performance.now();

Also, it's not a good practice to create variables globally. That's why const and let came in action.

Comment: I understand referencing the global namespace is not a good idea. I say that in my original post. But I don't understand what you mean by "//global namesapce c = performance.now()..." Would you be able to make a Fiddle or something to explain that please?